# archive_page() from archive module in drupal 6 shows all nodes not date specific

Tags: 6, nodes, theming, datetime

I installed [Archive module](http://drupal.org/project/archive) and used following code in a custom template:

```
print archive_page('all', 2012, 10, 12);
```

but it shows every single node I posted, How can I make it load nodes according to date I specified in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested archive page in Drupal 6.26 and using Archive 6.x - 1.4 . It is working as expected.  Maybe you are  date and month in the archive_page. Please find the detailed explanation below.

The parameters of `archive_page()` are the following ones:

- $year
  Number of year.
- $month
  Number of month.
- $day
  Number of day.

So `print archive_page('all', 2012, 10, 12);` will return the nodes created on October 12, 2012. I just followed the below process to verify the functionality.

- I installed archive module
- I enabled the module
- I enabled content types in "admin/settings/archive"
- I created two pages using Page one, and Page two as titles

  - Page one's authored date is October 13, 2012
  - Page two's authored date is October 15, 2012
- I enabled the PHP filter module
- I created a block with the below code, and enabled it on the right side bar

  ```
  module_load_include('inc', 'archive', 'archive.pages');
  print archive_page('all', 2012, 10,  13);
  ```

It does display the following output where only "Page one" is the one authored on October 13, 2012.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: +100 Thanks, I did as you said but it didn't work for me. anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is How I fix my problem:

Created a view that prints out months (link), enabled pagination and added some fields to print and now I get months list with post titles in pages.